# How do I write swagger documentation for an Optional enum definition?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have an API that looks similar to

```
public Optional<Status> getStatus
```

But cannot figure out how the swagger spec definition should look. The swagger.io editor error message for the following doesn't mean much:

```
get:
  ...
  responses:
    '200':
      description: OK
      schema:
        $ref: '#/definitions/Status'

definitions:
  Status:
    properties:
      type: string
      description: Blah
      enum:
        - UNKNOWN
```

Answer (score 0):

Was just the outer 'properties' property causing the problem (as string not object):

```
definitions:
  Status:
    type: string
    description: Blah
    enum:
      - UNKNOWN
```